# Highlight current week in weekly rotation

Tags: google-sheets

Good Afternoon,

I am working on building a schedule that essentially uses a 3-week rotation to determine who is responsible for what tasks. I am trying to automate which week is highlighted and from there be able to automate which names show up.

Given a start day of say 7/4/2021 being week A, how can I identify all future week A, Week B, or Week Cs.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, {SEQUENCE(
 TODAY()+1500-"7/4/2021", 1, "7/4/2021"), 
 "Week "&CHAR(64+ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FLATTEN(ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP((
 TODAY()+1500-"7/4/2021")/7), 7)/7)-ROUNDDOWN(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP((
 TODAY()+1500-"7/4/2021")/7), 1, 0)/3)*3), 
 TODAY()+1500-"7/4/2021", 1))}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("Week "&CHAR(65+ROUNDDOWN(MOD((B2:2-"2021/04/07")/21,3))))
```